# Customize and create a spinner in android studio

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, dart, spinner

Peace be upon you. Hello. How do I add a spinner like the one in this Samsung apps? Thank you very much, and may God reward you with good rewards[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM4q7.jpg)

Comment: Are you looking for a [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html)?

Comment: It's not clear what language you want a solution for. Flutter or Java? Why does the IDE matter? Please clarify you question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
<string-array name="array_name">
<item>Array Item 1</item>
<item>Array Item 2</item>
<item>Array Item 3</item>
</string-array>
```

In your layout:

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/array_name"
/>
```